# C++ code refactoring for if scenario

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, refactoring

I'm looking to refactor the c++ code for if conditions which will reduce the number of lines of code as well as it should have min complexity.

Here is the example:

```
if (xyz->a != cmd->aa)
{
   xyz->a = cmd->aa;
   obj->isFound = true;  //common code for all ifs
}


if (xyz->b != cmd->bb)
{
    xyz->b = cmd->bb;
    obj->isFound = true; 
}
```

And so on.. Here a, b, aa, bb are defined as a struct element.

Another example having if condition with arrays:

```
 if (abc->r16[0] != cmd->r0m)
    {
        abc>r16[0] = cmd->r0m;
        obj->isFound = true; //some common code for all ifs
    }


if (abc->r16[1] != cmd->r1m)
        {
            abc>r16[1] = cmd->r1m;
            obj->isFound = true; //some common code for all ifs
        }
```

And so on for r16[0] to r16[15]. Here r16[15] is defined inside struct.

Last scenario is for if condition with multidimensional array:

```
     if (pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[0][0] != cmd->obj0000)
           {
              pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[0][0] = cmd->obj0000
              obj->isFound = true; //some common code for all ifs
           }

if (pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[1][0] != cmd->obj0100)
           {
              pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[1][0] = cmd->obj0100
              obj->isFound = true; //some common code for all ifs
           }

if (pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[2][0] != cmd->obj0000)
           {
              pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[2][0] = cmd->obj0200
              obj->isFound = true; //some common code for all ifs
           }
```

Here c_0_15_r_0_15[2][0] will go through [0][0] to [15][0] and then [0][1] to [15][1] and so on...

For all such if condition scenario there will me 100's of if statements which should be reduced. How can we refactor such code?

Comment: can your provide an [mcve]?

Comment: Sounds like a better fit for CodeReview.

Comment: All these conditions are in different functions in same file with 1000's of line of code. Let me know which part of question is confusing you or if you need any specific information. @NathanOliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the duplication in your code. As you already aware - the following scheme is duplicated many times:

```
if (a != b)
{
    a = b;
    found = true;
}
```

So - encapsulate this in a function (template if there are multiple types:

```
template <typename Dst, typename Src>
inline void updateIfNeeded(Dst& dst, const Src& src, bool& wasNeeded)
{
    if (dst != src)
    {
        dst = src;
        wasNeeded = true;
    }
}
```

See - how it helps:

```
updateIfNeeded(abc->r16[0], cmd->r0m, obj->isFound);
updateIfNeeded(abc->r16[1], cmd->r1m, obj->isFound);
// ...
updateIfNeeded(pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[0][0], cmd->obj0000, obj->isFound);
updateIfNeeded(pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[1][0], cmd->obj0100, obj->isFound);
// ...
```

So far - reduction is quite big - and it is much more readable what is going on in this code.

---

What I see more - `obj->isFound` is repeating many times - maybe - some encapsulation in a class this time:

```
class Updater
{
public:
    bool anyUpdateWasNeeded = false;

    template <typename Dst, typename Src>
    void  updateIfNeeded(Dst& dst, const Src& src)
    {
       if (dst != src)
       {
           dst = src;
           anyUpdateWasNeeded = true;
       }
   }
};
```

You see - not needed to pass `obj->isFound` so many times:

```
Updater upd;

upd.updateIfNeeded(abc->r16[0], cmd->r0m);
upd.updateIfNeeded(abc->r16[1], cmd->r1m);
// ...
upd.updateIfNeeded(pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[0][0], cmd->obj0000);
upd.updateIfNeeded(pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[1][0], cmd->obj0100);
// ...
obj->isFound = upd.anyUpdateWasNeeded;
```

---

Frankly, at this point I would consider to use preprocessor - I mean to shorten all these arrays update - this is because on left you have arrays - on right you have many fields of similar names ("indexed" names...?)

But using preprocessor is bad style - let try to update arrays with pure C++:

```
class Updater
{
public:
    bool anyUpdateWasNeeded = false;

    template <typename Dst, typename Src>
    void  updateIfNeeded(Dst& dst, const Src& src);

    template <typename Dst, typename Src1, typename ...Src>
    void  updateArrayIfNeeded(Dst* dst, const Src1& src1, const Src& ...src)
    {
       updateIfNeeded(*dst, src1);
       updateArrayIfNeeded(dst + 1, src...);
   }
    template <typename Dst>
    void  updateArrayIfNeeded(Dst* dst) 
    {
        // nothing left
    }
};
```

So - this is what left:

```
upd.updateArrayIfNeeded(abc->r16, cmd->r0m, cmd->r1m, ....);
upd.updateArrayIfNeeded(pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[0], cmd->obj0000, cmd->obj0001, ...);
upd.updateArrayIfNeeded(pqr->c_0_15_r_0_15[1], cmd->obj0100, ...);
// ...
obj->isFound = upd.anyUpdateWasNeeded;
```

And so on...

Comment: You gave that abstraction a *much better* name.

Comment: @DanielJour - that a matter of taste... Anyway - OP will rename it probably

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in some function, for a start:

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
void flagSetIfNEq(Lhs & lhs, Rhs const & rhs, bool & flag) {
  if (lhs != rhs) {
    lhs = rhs;
    flag = true;
  }
}
// call it like
flagSetIfNEq(xyz->a, uvw->aa, obj->found)!
```

I'm assuming that `found` in your code is of type `bool`.

Though if you have that "100s of times" in your code you probably should consider a more aggressive refactoring.

And give that function a better name.